# Node.js app crashing with an R10 error

Tags: node.js, heroku, next.js

I am trying to successfully deploy a Node/React project on Heroku and after hours of debugging issues (I am a new developer) I think I got it near the finish line but now Heroku is posing some issues with deployment.

For background, here is my package.json file so you know what I have installed:

```
{
  "name": "StarterApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.4.1",
    "npm": "6.1.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "next": "^4.2.3",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-gyp": "^3.7.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.1",
    "sha3": "^1.2.2",
    "solc": "^0.4.24",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.3",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34"
  }
}
```

This is what I have in my server.js file:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
createServer(handler).listen(5000, (err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Ready on localhost:5000');
});
```

This is what Heroku suggests the code to look like ([source](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error)):

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(Our app is running on port ${ PORT });
});
```

The problem I am running into is that I am not sure how to merge what I already have with what Heroku wants me to use.  My code is necessary so that it works with NextJS and the Heroku code is agnostic of that.  What can I do to make the two work together? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it seems.  I just did the following:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  createServer(handler).listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Ready on localhost:5000');
  });
```

Doing that allowed me to use both NextJS and Heroku suggested code.